# Microsoft Azure - same login for windows app and web app

Tags: .net, azure, adal

I created two separate apps

1. browser app (web app)
    For authentication I am using adal.js, and its working fine.
2. non browser app (console app)
    for authentication adal.net and its working fine.

Problem:
For both browser app and for non browser, I have to login. so twice login on same machine.

Question.

What to do to merge these web and console app to one application, where user can authenticate once (single sign in ) and use both console app and web app.

Answer (score 1):

As your applications are separate, essentially in the background meaning a different application ID and set of keys then merging the logins will not be possible. The authentication is based on OAuth so each application is treated as a separate resource meaning you'll need a valid token to authenticate requests against it.

Think of it another way, if you login to say Facebook or Twitter who both use OAuth then you login to the website, you have to login to the application on the mobile device again, that token cannot be used for another application.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser you were using.

If you were using the same browser for the web app and console app, the Azure AD will issue the cookies when you first time. And then the second sign-in request should be sign-in without users enter the credential again based on the cookies.

Comment: Right, but my question is related to non browser and browser, let suppose we have web app and then outlook.

Comment: Based on my understanding, in this kind of scenario, it is expected that the second time sign-in required to reenter the credential since the Azure AD can't detect the sign-in user in the second request.